# How to read a CSV File and store it in the form of arrays Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My CSV file:

```
Interface   PHY Protocol    Description
Eth0/0/1    up  up  ***Another-Text-Here***
Eth0/0/2    up  up  ***Some-Text-Here***
Eth0/0/3    up  up  ***Connected-to-Camera***
Eth0/0/4    up  up  ***Some-Services-Ltd***
```

I want to show in the same format while executing the bash file

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Requirements alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In addition to what @jww mentioned, your file is not a Comma Separated Values file.

Comment: @AlterEgo: _I want to show in the same format while executing the bash file_  ... A `cat YOURFILE.csv` would do that.

Comment: @AlterEgo : And, you did not specify how the arrays are supposed to look like.

Comment: @user1934428 Since the csv is used in a bash script, cat command has to be executed inside shell. cat <filename> would do no help. 
Correct way is 
echo "$(cat textfile.csv)"

Comment: `cat FILENAME` does display the content of FILENAME to stdout and hence "shows" the file (unless you have your own definition of _showing_). `$(cat FILENAME)` on its own would just be replaced by the content of a file (and can be shorter written `$(<FILENAME)`), so, unless you use this in an assignment, it wouldn't produce anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

CSV means comma separated values but there is a possibility that non-comma field separators are used. CSV file format is not fully standardised. So we can give the benefit of doubt to the "Question asker" that the delimiter here in the question is tab or space. You can visit the wiki which also highlights the same thing in its 3rd paragraph, quoting here:

***In addition, the term "CSV" also denotes some closely related delimiter-separated formats that use different field delimiters, for example, semicolons. These include tab-separated values and space-separated values. A delimiter that is not present in the field data (such as tab) keeps the format parsing simple. These alternate delimiter-separated files are often even given a .csv extension despite the use of a non-comma field separator. This loose terminology can cause problems in data exchange. Many applications that accept CSV files have options to select the delimiter character and the quotation character. Semicolons are often used in some European countries, such as Italy, instead of commas.***

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Now answering the question of @Ego :

1. Incase you want to show in the same format while executing the bash file:
   `echo "$(cat testfile.csv)"`
2. Incase you want to store it in array using bash script:

```
index=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    testarray["$index"]="$line"
    index=$((index + 1));
done < testfile.csv
```

***Print each line. In this case, each line is stored as an item in an array.***

```
for eachline in "${testarray[@]}"
  do
    echo "$eachline"
  done
```

Instead of echo, you can perform some action on the individual line.